# When is a group ring an integral domain

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, group-rings

If $R$ is an integral domain (I am having $\mathbb{Z}$ or a field in mind) and $G$ a (not necessarily finite) group then 
we can form the group ring $R(G)$.

Note that if $g^{n+1} = e$ then $(e-g)(e+g\ldots + g^n) = e - g^{n+1} = 0$. This means
if $G$ has torsion then $R(G)$ always has zero-divisors.

What about the inverse? So if $G$ is torsion-free does that imply $R(G)$ having no zero-divisors.

Comment: Note that if $R=\mathbb{C}$ then there is the very famous Kaplansky conjecture that if $G$ is torsion-free then in $\mathbb{C}G$ there are no nontrivial idempotents (ie elements $p$ such that $p^2=p$ and $p=\neq 1, 0$. This is related because a nontrivial idempotent give you a zero divisor by looking at $p(1-p)$. The Kaplansky conjecture is true for many torsion-free groups, but remains open in general.

Comment: Over a field, this is called Kaplansky zero divisor conjecture. See this [MO thread](http://mathoverflow.net/q/79559/35324) and that other [MO thread](http://mathoverflow.net/q/33460/35324) for references. I guess it is still open, since google does not lead to any complete solution.

Comment: @OwenSizemore I believe that's an answer. You may want to post it as such.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By embedding $R$ into its field of fractions, we may as well assume that $R$ is a field. But then this is precisely Kaplansky's zero-divisor conjecture. This is a hard problem which is still open (2014). It has only been solved for certain classes of groups. If $R$ has characteristic $0$ then it suffices to treat $R=\mathbb{C}$ and there analytical methods are available. A reference is

> Passman, Donald S. *The algebraic structure of group rings*. Pure and Applied Mathematics. Wiley-Interscience [John Wiley & Sons], New York-London-Sydney, 1977.

For a summary of the known results, see [MO/79559](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/79559/what-is-the-current-status-of-the-kaplansky-zero-divisor-conjecture-for-group-ri).